# Book: capital letter for chapter "number", normal letter for equation numbering in chapter

Tags: equations, numbering, chapters

The code below creates a chapter with capital I as chapter "number".

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{8}%
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}%
\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{equation}
    e = mc^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

And hence all equations in the chapter will be numbered as I.x (x being the number of the equation in the chapter).

[image: captial I equation]

I would prefer that in equations the I would however not be capitalized, e.g.:

[image: normal i equation]

I it possible to do this without changing the chapter numbering (I want to keep that capitalised).

Thanks!

Comment: `\renewcommand\theequation{\alph{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}`

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot! 

btw: when you switch back to arabic chapter numbering, you should once again renew the equation numbering `\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}`

Comment: I think it would book better with `scroman` numbering of chapters (in equations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as simple as

```
\renewcommand\theequation{\alph{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
```

Normally this definition contains `\thechapter` but one can do what ever